# DevExpress XtraReport is running in background even though tab is closed

Tags: devexpress, xtrareport

I have created an XtraReport which has 5 subreports.

This report is quite large which consist of 10000 pages. While the report is being generated if I close the browser's tab the report is still generating in the background whereas if I click the progress bar's cancel button the report generation process is abandoned.

My question is how can I stop the report generation when I close the browser's tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen how it does in their online demos. In short, you can do this on the window events beforeunload, focus, blur.
Code from demos.devexpress.com/MVCxReportDemos:

```js
(function() {
    var doWithViewer = function(func) {
        var viewer = window['webDocumentViewer'];
        viewer && func(viewer);
    };
    var stopTimeout;
    window.addEventListener("focus", function() { stopTimeout && clearTimeout(stopTimeout); });
    window.addEventListener("blur", function() {
        stopTimeout && clearTimeout(stopTimeout);
        stopTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
            doWithViewer(function(viewer) {
                var reportPreview = viewer.GetReportPreview();
                reportPreview && reportPreview.documentBuilding() && reportPreview.stopBuild();
            });
        }, 3000);
    });
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
        doWithViewer(function(viewer) {
            setTimeout(function() { viewer.Close(); }, 1);
        });
    });
})()
```